# Click doesnt trigger on first click, SquareSpace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering why did my code didn't work on first click, the flow was when I click on header title on the site, it suppose to be open new window overriding pop up blocker, but its only triggered when 2nd time click on the title.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href$="exbound/"]').click(function(){
      window.open ('externalsite.com', 'newwindow', config='height=600, width=800, '
        + 'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, '
        + 'directories=no, status=no');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your jQuery version is really old. jQuery is on version 3.1.1 now. Maybe try using a newer version of jQuery (I doubt it would yield more favorable results, but doesn't hurt to try). I recommend providing a complete example of your problem, including your HTML code.

Comment: @anub13 he means change the first line to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">`

Comment: @DrewKennedy thanks, I have changed it... it doesn't work, and as the description above, its on Square Space, so it doesnt have html, its on header code injection

It was work with this code



<script type="text/javascript">
      if(document.URL.indexOf("mysite.com") > -1){
  window.open ('externalsite.com', 'newwindow', config='height=600, width=800, '
    + 'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, '
    + 'directories=no, status=no');
 }



but since its block pop up, I want to override it..

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent Thanks, was not realize..

Comment: @anub13 This code should work fine, like this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/delvarworld/atg5m6ym/7743/ . Are there any other click handlers bound to a tags? That could be interfering.

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks for replying, but I have tried that, and its applies to all which has <a href> tag
So when ever I click on header title(doesnt specified), the jquery triggered and as my code does, its work on 2nd click...

No, there are no other click handlers bound to a tags... Only that one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $("a[href$='exbound/']").click(function(){
           window.open("http://externalsite.com", "_blank", config='height=600, width=800, '
    + 'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, '
    + 'directories=no, status=no');
     });
    });
```

working code here http://codepen.io/UserIsMonica/pen/zovvEp

Comment: @anub13 i don't know where is your searching string "exbound/" in href you specify here a[href$="exbound/"] but it will work with href$ if its end of URL and with href* will work anywhere in URL

Comment: thanks for answering, but the logic is same like mine...
I have tried it, and it doesnt work on 1st click.
Yes, my aim was last url string, so I used $ instead *.

Comment: @anub13 have a look now its working well on code pen.

Comment: Yes, I have take a look at it, it does work as it should be, the site was on SquareSpace...
From the code also basically its same as mine.. you only changed from $ to *
The idea is the same..

Comment: @anub13 in my updated codepen link i have used $ as you used but website is opening in new window. what else you want ?

Comment: thanks for answering, but I have did it, and re-checking if I am missing something
But its same as mine, triggered when 2nd click not 1st click.

Comment: http://www.nationalgeographic.com/

Took an example, when you are on that screen, clicked on Subscribe, pop up new window.
The flow exactly like that.

Answer (score 0):

I end up adding class to the title link

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href$="exbound/"]').addClass('popup');
  $(".popup").click(function(){
   window.open ('xternalsite.com', 'newwindow', config='height=600, width=800, '
   + 'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, '
   + 'directories=no, status=no');
  });
 });
</script>
```

and at first was 2nd click also, and I realize it was wrong placed injecting code, supposed to be in all header page, but instead I only place them in the page where I want to click it.